# Airflow cannot access local files in python code

Tags: python-import, airflow

I have a folder structure:

```
root_folder
  - file.conf
  - models
    - __init__.py
    - model1.py
  - airflow
    - dags
      - dag1.py
```

so in the above case `dag1` imports `model1`. When doing so it breaks because `models/__init__.py` loads the `file.conf` file. I tried adding root folder to `sys.path` through `sys.path.append` that doesn't seem to solve the problem. I also tried relative paths from init but still it cannot locate the file given through relative path. What is a good way to bundle your own code with airflow code?

After trying various ways to make it work, what seems to work for me is using absolute path of the files as `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__ ,"../..") + '/file.conf')`. If you know a better way please answer below. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the code you are using to load file.conf?

Comment: `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__ ,"../..") + '/file.conf')`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `__init__.py` file inside the root_folder:

`-root_folder
  - __init__.py
  - file.conf
  - models
    - __init__.py
    - model1.py
  - airflow
    - dags
      - dag1.py`

Then add to $PYTHONPATH the path to your root_folder.

Finally in the dag1.py file import:

`import file.conf`

and also you can import

`import models.model1`

Comment: ERROR - attempted relative import with no known parent package